# Material UI popover show blue box while opening

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I open Material UI popover, it shows this blue box:

[image: Blue box]

I tried to remove this but couldn't find a solution.

[Highlighted Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaoLX.png)

Comment: Would you mind taking a larger screenshot and providing a more detailed description of the picture? It would be helpful for us to better understand the context.

Comment: @TasosTsournosI added one more picture. Hope it'll help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RMJazib Show us a bit of your code. It's hard to determine whats going wrong.